# Can Observable.FromEvent be used with DataContextChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I want to get the DataContext of a control as an IObservable.  I've tried this:

```
Observable.FromEvent<DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler,
     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>
     (a => this.DataContextChanged += a, a => this.DataContextChanged -= a)
     .Subscribe(e => MessageBox.Show(e.NewValue.ToString()));
```

Which compiles fine, but at the point where Subscribe is called it throws the exception: Error binding to target method.

My guess is that this is because DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs doesn't inherit from event args, but I'm not sure.  Any advice on the right way to do this would be apreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the other overloads for FromEvent allows you to create the delegate yourself from a method.  Allowing you to do this:

```
Observable.FromEvent
    <DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>
    (a => new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(
        new Action<object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>((s, e) => a(e))),
        h => this.DataContextChanged += h, h => this.DataContextChanged -= h)
        .Subscribe(e => MessageBox.Show(e.NewValue.ToString()));
```

which seems to work

Comment: @Tuskan460 - You can simplify `a => new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(new Action<object, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs>((s, e) => a(e)))` down to `a => (s, e) => a(s, e)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 'hit the nail on the head', for some reason `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` is a struct, and hence does not inherit `EventArgs`. See this related blog post:

http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/12/10/5430331.aspx

This makes it impossible to handle this event using a generic event handling mechanism.

I guess you will have to handle this event in your own code and create an `Observable` manually.

Answer (score 0):

The custom implementation would be as simple as:

```
Observable.CreateWithDisposable<DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler>(obs =>
{
   var subject = new Subject<DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler>();
   //Attach event handler and on event call OnNext of subject with the value
   return subject.Subscribe(obs);
});
```

**UPDATED** : To handle event handler removal

```
public class GenericDisposable : IDisposable
        {
            Action _act = null;
            IDisposable _disp = null;
            public GenericDisposable(Action act,IDisposable disp)
            {
                _act = act;
                _disp = disp;
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                _act();
                _disp.Dispose();
            }
        }
        public static IObservable<DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler> CreateForEvent()
        {
            return Observable.Defer(() =>
            {
                return Observable.CreateWithDisposable<DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler>(obs =>
                {
                    var subject = new Subject<DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler>();
                    //Attach event handler and on event call OnNext of subject with the value
                    return new GenericDisposable(() => {/*remove event handler*/}, subject.Subscribe(obs));
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: This will never detach the event handler though, even if you unsubscribed from the observable.

Comment: Yes, but that is not usually the requirement.Although you can go the complex way to handle all those edge cases.

Comment: true, often this isn't a requirement, and I don't specifically need it now, I just feel it would be nice to have when solving the problem more generally.